# Alterar itens do sidemenu em Ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic, ionic4

Estou migrando um projeto do ionic 3.2 para o 5.14, e estou com dificuldades para usar observables em vez de events.

No código original, após o usuário logar, eu alterava o nome e a imagem do sidemenu através de events:

**login.pages.ts**

```
this.events.publish('user:login', this.nomePrimeiro, Date.now());
this.events.publish('image:login', this.imagem, Date.now());
```

e no **app.component.ts** eu coloquei isto:

```
events.subscribe('user:login', (user, time) => {
  Global.nomePrimeiro = user;
});

events.subscribe('image:login', (image, time) => {
  Global.imagem = image;
});
```

Como fazer o mesmo com Observables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente você está lidando com evento de login. Nesse caso, o aconselhável é utilizar o [guard](https://medium.com/@rogerioadris/protegendo-seu-aplicativo-ionic-com-guards-a52433dc1d07). Mais detalhes [aqui](https://youtu.be/EBHX3YLM1Yg?t=1528).

De toda forma, para fazer a comunicação entre dois components você pode criar um serviço intermediário. Por exemplo, crie o **login.service.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

  // Observable string sources
  private userSource = new Subject<string>();
  private imageSource = new Subject<string>();

  // Observable string streams
  user$ = this.userSource.asObservable();
  image$ = this.imageSource.asObservable();

  // Service message commands
  anunciarUsuario(user) {
    this.userSource.next(user);
  }

  anunciarImagem(image) {
    this.imageSource.next(image);
  }
}
```

Aí na **login.pages.ts**:

```
constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

anunciarUsuario() {
    let usuario = { user: this.nomePrimeiro, time: Date.now() };
    this.userService.anunciarUsuario(usuario);
  }

anunciarImagem() {
    let image = { image: this.imagem, time: Date.now() };
    this.userService.anunciarImagem(imagem);
  }
```

E por fim, no **app.component.ts**:

```
  userSubscription: Subscription;
  imageSubscription: Subscription;


  constructor(private loginService: LoginService) {
    this.userSubscription = loginService.user$.subscribe(
      user => {
        Global.nomePrimeiro = user.user;
    });
    this.imageSubscription = loginService.image$.subscribe(
      image => {
        Global.imagem = image.image;
    });
  }
```

Eu criei 2 serviços porque seu código estava assim, mas acredito que apenas 1 serviço poderia mandar os dados de usuário e de imagem, deixando tudo bem mais simples. De toda forma, isso deve funcionar, mas fica ainda a sugestão de utilizar os guards para proteger as rotas da sua aplicação.

E também pode consultar [aqui](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service) para mais detalhes sobre a comunicação entre componenetes.

Comment: Obrigado, resolvi o problema com um único service, mas dentro do que você colocou.